# Como decir "for a while"

Tags: traducción, modismos

Let's say I want to say "On a typical day I read for a while, and then I go to bed." 
Would the best way to see this be: "En un día típico, yo leo un rato y después me acuesto".

More specifically, I'm interested in the translation for "for a while" in Spanish. Is it `por un rato` or just `un rato`? If it is not `un rato`, is there any case where just using `un rato` is acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"**En un día típico, (yo) leo un rato, y después, me acuesto**"* is very accurate.

In Spanish, "for a while" can be written as "durante un rato," or "por un rato," but normally, one would say "un rato."

However, one may write the following sentence:

- "on a typical day, I read for two hours,"

as either of the following:

- "en un día típico, (yo) leo dos horas,"
- "en un día típico, (yo) leo durante dos horas,"
- "en un día típico, (yo) leo por dos horas."

Answer (score 2):

Tanto

> En un día típico, yo leo un rato y después me acuesto

como

> En un día típico, yo leo **por** un rato y después me acuesto

Son válidas, aunque ciertamente algunos hablantes favorecerán una sobre la otra. Tanto `por` como `durante` sirven para expresar la duración cuando una acción se prolonga en el tiempo, así que incluso podrías decir

> En un día típico, yo leo **durante** un rato y después me acuesto

para explicar que esta  acción se prolonga en el tiempo. Sin embargo, puedes omitir tanto `por` como `durante` (que es la primera opción) y se te entenderá perfectamente. Nadie pensará que lo que lees es "un rato", sino que entenderán que  la acción de leer se prolonga por un breve espacio de tiempo.